# Reading tweets using the command line

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to read Twitter using the command line. Until a few days ago, `wget` was good enough. But since a few days ago, doing

```
    wget https://twitter.com/climagic
```

"works"... but the file `climagic` contains only a error message:

```
    We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you like to proceed to legacy Twitter?

    (BUTTON) Yes

    Something went wrong, but don’t fret — let’s give it another shot.
    Try again
```

I'm aware of the existence of several CLI Twitter-reading programs, but AFAIK, all require using a Twitter account.
Some ideas?

Comment: Tried using a text based browser? Such as Lynx.

Comment: @bxm,  "clicking" in the "(BUTTON)" gives the error message `Alert!: HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed`.  In any case, I'm interested in non-interactive reading.

Comment: A quick Google suggests they have ceased legacy Twitter, which may explain your experience. You may have to make use of the API rather than scraping from web content, but I imagine that’s going to require setting up an appropriate account.

Comment: @bxm, OK. Thanks.